# can we check url validity with jquery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validating url with jQuery without the validate-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723140/validating-url-with-jquery-without-the-validate-plugin)

is there any jquery method to check a url is valid?

or can jquery get `http header`? some code method like this.

js code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var url = $('#url').val();
  // check a url is valid?
});
```

html code:

```
<input id="url" name="url" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723140/validating-url-with-jquery-without-the-validate-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some information that I found:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#commentForm").validate({
              rules: {
                 field: {
                    required: true,
                    url : true
                 }
              }
           });
        });
        </script>
```

[Source of information](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/ajax/jquery/url.html)

[Another person already answered this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2568852/1332394)

[Link to jQuery URL Method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm getting you right, you can do a `$.ajax()` to the url and see the response status codes.

You can set different methods for the statuses you get.

Check this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `$.ajax` must obey the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  This will only work if the URLs are to the same domain as the page.

Comment: Yes, same domain policy applies, unless CORS is enabled on target server. Another option is to send AJAX request to your server which makes http request and returnes result to client