# URL validation both in php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, validation, url

I found lots of url validation method in this website and also in others. But i can not find the exact one that is required for my project. Here is what i need.

```
<form name="example" value="">
 <input type='text' name='link' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="" />    
 </form>
```

Now if someone type a link in the text field then i have to check whether the link is valid or not.
Valid link will be like

```
1. http://www.example.com
2. www.example.com
3. example.com
4. (some space) then one of the three links above
5. one of the three links above then some space
```

These are the valid formats. Anything else is typed in the text field should give output invalid link

I require the solution both in javascript and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This handles all your cases on php side

```
$regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME
        $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass
        $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP
        $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port
        $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path
        $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query
        $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor


    //    $url = 'http://www.domain.dk/seo/friendly/url';

        if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", trim($url)))
        {
        print 'true';
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can find this javascript url validation answer with following post

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303872/url-validation-using-javascript
```

For php validation find below the code

```
function isValidURL($url)
{
return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}

if(!isValidURL($fldbanner_url))
{
$errMsg .= "* Please enter valid URL including http://<br>";
}
```

Comment: Your regular expression implies that `http://` is mandatory. User wants to accept URL with or without protocol prefix.

Comment: That matches 1/5 of his request.

Comment: preg_match ("/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9](\.[a-z]{2,4})+$/i", $url)

this preg_match might solve your problem