# Issue with regex for website validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using the following regex to validate a website:

```
^((https?):\/\/)?([w|W]{3}\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$
```

This is currently working for:

```
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
```

but not for

```
google.com
http://google.com
```

Please help.

Comment: try ([w|W]{3}\.|) - note the | is all I added

Comment: Throw it out. That regex is awful. It bans a lot of perfectly valid hostnames. Learn how URLs work and start again.

Comment: The pipe `|` is seen as a literal character inside a character class and doesn't mean "OR". A character class is only a set of characters, character ranges, and shorthand character class like `\s` or `\d`. if you want a case-insensitive pattern, use the `i` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make thr group matching `www.` optional

```
^((https?):\/\/)?([wW]{3}\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$
                            ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD5jG3/1)

I am just pointing how to adjust your regex to match the strings you specified. Actually, the topic has been thoroughly covered on SO. For example, please check [Trying to Validate URL Using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303872/trying-to-validate-url-using-javascript) post to see how URL can be validated in JavaScript.

Also, a bit of searching over the Web can show some other solutions, like in [URL Validation using Regular Expression in Javascript](http://blog.roymj.co.in/url-validation-using-regular-expression-javascript/):

```
^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$
```

It is a bit adjusted, see [how it works here](https://regex101.com/r/aD5jG3/2).

Comment: I have used the regex that you have specified 1st i.e. ^((https?):\/\/)?([wW]{3}\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$.... it is working for most cases. 1 of the cases that it has nt worked is: www...google.com :(

Comment: You mean it should not match, right? Then try adding a negative lookahead `(?![^.]*\.\.)`: `^(?![^.]*\.\.)((https?):\/\/)?([wW]{3}\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$`.

Comment: yes . this works.. bt again not for wwww.google.com .

Comment: @Simone: Surely it won't, we specified `w` to repeat only 3 times: `[wW]{3}`. If you plan to allow more, just add `,`: `[wW]{3,}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82286/discussion-between-simone-and-stribizhev).