# how 2 repeat a part of a regex and the nthe rest of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match this string
`domain1.com,domain2.com,domain3.com###someString`

So I need a regex that matches all 3 domains and the #someString.
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593669/936965) pattern to validate url's, so I thought I could use that regex to filter domains as well.

```
/^(http|https):\/\/(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+@)?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3})|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-\u00C0-\u017F]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))(:[0-9]+)?(\/(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(\/([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)*)?(\?([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?(\#([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?)?$/
```

I changed it to this so `http(s)://` is not required, there will never be a protocol before a domain name:

```
/^(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+@)?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3})|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-\u00C0-\u017F]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))(:[0-9]+)?(\/(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(\/([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)*)?(\?([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?(\#([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?)?$/
```

But ofcourse that would only match one domain and nothing more.
Unfortunately I don't have enough knowlegde to repeat this pattern so it would match my string.
I'd like to have this output:

```
match1:
    domain1.com
    domain2.com
    domain3.com

match2:
     #someString
```

I use Javascript only.

Comment: try `^(https?:\/\/)?`

Comment: https will never be in the domain, that's why I removed it.

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/dV4iR6/1), perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what you changed

Comment: @FIA2008: I added the necessary explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the anchors `^`/`$` so that the match could be found inside a larger string and add a subpattern to match `#` followed with 1 or more alphanumerics `#\w+`:

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+@)?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3})|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-\u00C0-\u017F]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))(:[0-9]+)?(\/(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(\/([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)*)?(\?([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?(\#([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?)?|#\w+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV4iR6/1)

JS snippet:

```js
var re = /(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+@)?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3})|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-\u00C0-\u017F]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))(:[0-9]+)?(\/(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(\/([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)*)?(\?([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?(\#([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?)?|#\w+/g; 
var str = 'domain1.com,domain2.com,domain3.com###someString';
var res = str.match(re)
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res);
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).