# Website URL validation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I need to validate Website URL using AngularJS `ng-pattern`.

I am using following code:

```
<label>Website Address</label>
<span><input type="text" class="form-factor" data-ng-pattern="/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i" data-ng-model="broker.websiteUrl"/></span>
```

But it only allows

```
http://test.com/
```

I need to allow the following URLs also

```
http://test.com
www.test.com
http://www.test.com
```

Please, suggest a way to validate website URLs in AngularJS.

Comment: why putting negative point??

Comment: Can you just use `<input type="url">`? [(docs)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Burl%5D)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your regular expression. Creating an absolutely perfect URL validator expression is a challenging task. Please try this one:

```
"#([a-z]([a-z]|\d|\+|-|\.)*):(\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?((\[(|(v[\da-f]{1,}\.(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~)|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)+))\])|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(:\d*)?)(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*|(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)){0})(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\xE000-\xF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?#iS"
```

Also [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) is a great resource and a comparison table about various approaches to validate a url through regular expression.

---

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303872/trying-to-validate-url-using-javascript) is a question about validating urls. You can easily port these solutions to angular.

Comment: I tried with this expression.But its also only allowing **http://test.com**. Not allowing **www.test.com**