# Universal standard regular expression for URL validation?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

P.S: Please don't mark this as Duplicate, I've seen many other questions.
I have a set of URLs to be validated like:

`https://pqr-aaa.abc.xyz.com:8383`
`http://172.24.100.200:6767`
and many more. I'm validating them in javascript. I've seen *many* questions and *found* the regex I'm looking for. This seems to suit my need:

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?|^((http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

My question is that, is there a universal standard for URL validation regex that is used by everyone, or do we just use the regex suited for our needs?

Comment: If there exists a post asking about an universal Regexp for URL validation, and an answer providing such a Regexp, why shouldn't this question be marked as a dup?

Comment: I've seen that question, I'm asking whether there is a standard that is followed everywhere strictly :(

Comment: To me it looks like you're asking a RegExp, there is a [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) though.

Comment: @Teemu So, if I tweak my regex to that standard, then I'd be following the norms, right?

Comment: Well, kinda, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305082/1169519).

Comment: It appears bobince's answer is a bit outdated, though still correct what comes to regexps. Take a look at [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) at MDN.

Answer (score 0):

I believe below regex will work for all the URL validation:

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```

Comment: How about the other schemas, like ftp ..?

Comment: Also, the string `test....` matches your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/9OdZ43/1)

Answer (score 0):

This small change will allow another protocols beside `http/https` too

```
^(?:(http(s)?|gopher|ftp):\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]+$
```

Comment: Your regex also matches any string with at least 3 dots after it (such as `test....`)